# APA references with bibtex: some fields not working

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-philosophy

I'm trying to reference some sheet music in a bibliography.

The work was composed by Mussorgsky in 1867, but re-written ("arranged") by Rimsky-Korsakov in 1886 and published by W. Bessel & Co. out of St. Petersburg.

The APA guidelines [here](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/musical-score-references) and [here](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/09/how-to-cite-a-musical-score.html)  are clear.  The reference should look like this:

> Mussorgsky, M. (Composer). (1886). Night on Bare Mountain (Rimsky-Korsakov, N. Arr.) [Sheet Music]. St. Petersburg: W. Bessel & Co. (Original work published 1867)

or more generally:

> author (role). (date). title (editor, editortype) [entrysubtype] location: publisher. (Original work published origdate)

However, the closest I can get is:

> Mussorgsky, M. (1886). Night on bare mountain (N. Rimsky-Korsakov, **typearranger**) [Sheet Music]. W. Bessel & Co. (Original work published 1867)

I got that by using the [biblatex documentation](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the [biblatex-apa documentation](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf) document to create the folowing `*.bib`:

```
@book{mussorgsky,
  author       = "Modest Mussorgsky",
  role         = "Composer",
  year         = "1886",
  title        = "Night On Bald Mountain",
  entrysubtype = "Sheet Music",
  editor       = "Nikolay Rimsky-Korsakov",
  editortype   = "arranger",
  location     = "St. Petersburg",
  publisher    = "W. Bessel \& Co.",
  origdate     = "1867"
}
```

Then I include this in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
```

The differences in descending order of priority:

1. The `role = "Composer"` is not respected.  Though APA guidelines describe this as a "role", I'm not surprised this didn't work because bibtex doesn't describe "role" the same way.  But is there a way I can get **"(Composer)"** in there?
2. If I leave `editortype` empty, Rimsky-Kosakov is credited here as an editor ("**Ed.**").  It would be more accurate to credit him as an arranger ("**Arr.**"), but the built-in `editortype` in biblatex only support `editor`, `compiler`, `founder`, `continuator`, `redactor`, `reviser`, `collaborator`, `organizer`.  Is there a way to extend this?
3. "St. Petersburg:" is missing.  If I try other "style" choices, then location appears before the publisher as expected.  Did I do something wrong, or should I just use `publisher = "St. Petersburg: W. Bessel \& Co."`?  Maybe APA has changed since 7th edition (when the music stuff was defined) but location is pretty important when referring to these really old publishers.  My current strategy is to merge the location field into the publisher field.

Comment: Note that the APA style blog that wants the "(Composer)" (https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/09/how-to-cite-a-musical-score.html) is for 6th-edition APA style, but current `biblatex-apa` implements 7th-edition APA style. The reference for 7th-edition APA style https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/musical-score-references does not have an explicit "(Composer)" in any of the examples.

Comment: Similarly the "St. Petersburg" is not needed with 7th-edition APA style as that generally drops the location and only has the publisher. None of the examples on https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/musical-score-references feature a location. (6th edition was different and wanted the location in several cases.)

Comment: Good answers for points 1 and 3.  I love how bibtex's implementation of APA is more current than my own knowledge.  I guess that's another benefit of bibtex over writing it out manually.  Looking forward to hearing about point 2.

Comment: you get the composer with `AUTHOR+an:role= {1="Composer"},` in the bib (if you really want it). And you can define a string for the Arr: `\NewBibliographyString{typearranger}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}
 {typearranger = {Arr.}}`

Comment: Fantastic!  That works!  If you write up an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.  If you don't care about the cred, then I'll write it up as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Adding a "(Role)" was true in the 6th edition APA, but is no longer required in 7th edition APA.   If you really want to add it, use:

```
author+an:role= {1="Composer"},
```

2. Add the following to the pre-amble to make `editortype` accept "arranger":

```
\NewBibliographyString{typearranger}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{typearranger = {Arr.}}
```

3. Location isn't required in 7th edition APA anymore.